# Making css loader on ajax search to stay more time

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I have ajax search function and I'm trying to add loader while results are loading. This is the function

```
function search(){
      var title=$("#search").val();

          if(title!=""){
             $("#result").html("<div class=\"loader09\"></div>");
             $.ajax({
                      type:"post",
                      url:"search.php",
                      data:"title="+title,
                      success:function(data){
                         $("#result").html(data);
                         $("#search").val("");
                    }
              });
       }   
}
```

Is it possible to make this loader `$("#result").html("<div class=\"loader09\"></div>");` to appear for longer time than it's needed? I mean currently it's appeared for 1sec because the search perform really fast. I want to stay at least 3-4 sec.

Comment: Might you explain why you would want to slow down a response to users? This seems counter-intuitive and a concern for usability.

Comment: Because I don't like it this fast and want to slow the page a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
success:function(data){
    setTimeout(function(data){ 
        $("#result").html(data);
        $("#search").val(""); 
    }, 3000);  <-- 3 second delay
}
```

or:

```
function delayedResponse(data) {
    setTimeout(function(data){ 
        $("#result").html(data);
        $("#search").val(""); 
    }, 3000);  <-- 3 second delay
}
```

with:

```
success:function(data){
    delayedResponse(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but with this doesn't load anything. Just loader icon and never show any result. There is no errors also in console.

Comment: Yes, nothing in console.

Comment: Still same.. it's showing results in < 1 sec and hiding the loader.